# Why aren't my buttons working?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I recently made my first app and went out to test it. When I opened the app on my phone I got 2 problems. The menu off my app does have 3 buttons, 1 to start a "1player game" 1 to start a "2player game" and 1 to exit the app. When I press the button to play a "1player game" there happens nothing. When I press the "2player game" button, the app closes with the error "unfortunately testjk was closed". I have literally no idea what I did wrong in my code. I also have no erros in my problems tab. Some help would be appreciated.

MainMenuScreen.java:

```
package com.wouter.testjk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainMenuScreen extends Activity {  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

        //1player

        findViewById(R.id.two_player).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "One Player Button Pressed!");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuScreen.this, TicTacToeGame.class);
                intent.putExtra("gameType", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        //2players
        findViewById(R.id.two_player).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Two Player Button Pressed!");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuScreen.this, TicTacToeGame.class);
                intent.putExtra("gameType", false);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        //exit game
        findViewById(R.id.exit_game).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Exit Game Button Pressed!");
                MainMenuScreen.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.wouter.testjk;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.wouter.testjk.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TicTacToeGame mGame;

    private Button mBoardButtons[];

    private TextView mInfoTextView;
    private TextView mPlayeroneCount;
    private TextView mTieCount;
    private TextView mPlayertwoCount;
    private TextView mPlayeroneText; 
    private TextView mPlayertwoText;

    private int mPlayeroneCounter = 0;
    private int mTieCounter = 0;
    private int mPlayertwoCounter = 0;

    private boolean mPlayeroneFirst = true;
    private boolean mIsSinglePlayer = false;
    private boolean mIsPlayerOneTurn = true;
    private boolean mGameOver = false;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boolean mGameType = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("gametype");

        mBoardButtons = new Button[mGame.getBOARD_SIZE()];
        mBoardButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        mBoardButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        mBoardButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        mBoardButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        mBoardButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        mBoardButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        mBoardButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        mBoardButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        mBoardButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

        Button mTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ten);
        mTen.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button mEleven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eleven);
        mEleven.setOnClickListener(this);



        mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
        mPlayeroneCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humancount);
        mTieCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiesCount);
        mPlayertwoCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.androidCount);
        mPlayeroneText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.human);
        mPlayertwoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.android);

        mPlayeroneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayeroneCounter));
        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
        mPlayeroneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayertwoCounter));

        mGame = new TicTacToeGame();

        startNewGame(mGameType);

    }

    private void startNewGame(boolean isSingle)
    {
        this.mIsSinglePlayer = isSingle;

        mGame.clearBoard();

        for (int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.length; i++)
        {
            mBoardButtons[i].setText("");
            mBoardButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
            mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));

        }
        if (mIsSinglePlayer)
        {
             mPlayeroneText.setText("speler: ");
             mPlayertwoText.setText("android: ");

             if (mPlayeroneFirst)
             {
                 mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.first_human);
                 mPlayeroneFirst = false;
             }
             else
             {
                 mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                 int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                 setMove(TicTacToeGame.PLAYER_TWO, move);
                 mPlayeroneFirst = true;
             }
        }
        else
        {
             mPlayeroneText.setText("speler 1: ");
             mPlayertwoText.setText("speler 2: ");

             if (mPlayeroneFirst)
             {
                 mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_player_one);
                 mPlayeroneFirst = false;
             }
             else
             {
                 mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_player_two);
                 mPlayeroneFirst = true;
             }

        }

        mGameOver = false;
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        int location;

        public ButtonClickListener(int location)
        {
            this.location = location;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!mGameOver)
            {
                if(mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
                {
                    if(mIsSinglePlayer)
                    {
                         setMove(TicTacToeGame.PLAYER_ONE, location);

                         int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                         if (winner == 0)
                         {
                             mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                             int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                             setMove(TicTacToeGame.PLAYER_TWO, move);
                             winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                         }
                         if (winner == 0)
                                 mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                         else if (winner == 1)
                         {
                             mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                             mTieCounter++;
                             mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                             mGameOver = true;
                         }       
                         else if (winner ==2)
                         {
                             mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                             mPlayeroneCounter++;
                             mPlayeroneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayeroneCounter));
                             mGameOver = true;
                         }
                         else if (winner ==3)
                         {
                             mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                             mPlayertwoCounter++;
                             mPlayertwoCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayertwoCounter));
                             mGameOver = true;
                         }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(mIsPlayerOneTurn)
                        {
                            setMove(TicTacToeGame.PLAYER_ONE, location);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            setMove(TicTacToeGame.PLAYER_TWO, location);                        
                        }


                        int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                        if (winner == 0)
                        {
                            if(mIsPlayerOneTurn)
                            {
                                mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_player_two);
                                mIsPlayerOneTurn = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_player_one);
                                mIsPlayerOneTurn = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (winner == 1)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                            mTieCounter++;
                            mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                        }       
                        else if (winner ==2)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.player_one_wins);
                            mPlayeroneCounter++;
                            mPlayeroneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayeroneCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                        }
                        else if (winner ==3)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.player_two_wins);
                            mPlayertwoCounter++;
                            mPlayertwoCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayertwoCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                     }
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }

    private void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mGame.setMove(player,location);
        mBoardButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
        if (player == TicTacToeGame.PLAYER_ONE)
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
        {
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId())
        {
        case R.id.ten:

            startNewGame(mIsSinglePlayer);
            return;

        case R.id.eleven:

            MainActivity.this.finish();
            return;

        }
    }
}
```

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wouter.testjk"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="3" >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenuScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" > 
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat: http://textuploader.com/on1k --------
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQt2Q.jpg -----------
I have no idea how else I should upload this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning both `OnClickListener`s to the same button `R.id.two_player`. That is, change the first one to `one_player`, as

```
// 1player
findViewById(R.id.one_player).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    // (...)
});

//2players
findViewById(R.id.two_player).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    // (...)
});
```

**EDIT**: as I see in the logcat, and also correctly pointed by Spidy in the comments, you need to declare your activity in the manifest.

```
11-15 23:45:28.227: E/AndroidRuntime(6056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 23:45:28.227: E/AndroidRuntime(6056): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.wouter.testjk/com.wouter.testjk.TicTacToeGame}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

**EDIT2**: It's pretty clear from the logs:

```
11-16 00:39:09.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7124): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 00:39:09.867: E/AndroidRuntime(7124): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.wouter.testjk/com.wouter.testjk.TicTacToeGame}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.wouter.testjk.TicTacToeGame cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

You are trying to instantiate the class TicTacToeGame as an activity, but it is not. I guess you wanted to go to the MainActivity. In that case, you must change your intent to something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is correct. Also, since the app is crashing, I'm assuming you forgot to put the TicTacToeGame activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Actually didnt fix the whole problem, the problem is still here. I added the manifest file

Comment: If possible, add also your logcat.

Comment: I will add it in 30mins

Comment: added the logcat in the post

Comment: I thought I declared them right in the manifest file, could you tell me what I should change/add?

Comment: Just add: <activity
            android:name=".TicTacToeGame"
            android:label="@string/app_name" > 
        </activity> to the 'application' node of your manifest.

Comment: I did this, but its still not working, im working on a new logcat file

Comment: Thanks this last fix did it, thank you so much for helping me out here! I am just started programming java and I really appreciate other helping help me!